# Is there a way to put program variables into a gridview's bound field values?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

What I mean is, I tried writing this:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Name" dataTextfield="name" DataNavigateUrlFormatString='~/admin/customer_edit.aspx?id={0}&type=<%= request.QueryString("type")%>' DataNavigateUrlFields="id" />
```

Well that didn't work, I just got the <%= business as text in my link. I tried it with <%# and that didn't work either.

I suppose I could do this by creating a template field, But is there a way to put program variable into a field parameter of a gridview or other control like you can do outside of gridviews? Why does something that works in general not work inside a gridview?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `runat="server"`?

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to assign `DataNavigateUrlFormatString` using a DataBind expression because it's not a bindable property. But you can set that from the Code-Behind:

```
(GridView1.Columns[0] as HyperLinkField).DataNavigateUrlFormatString = "~/admin/customer_edit.aspx?id={0}&type=" + Request.QueryString["type"];
```

Comment: Fair enough, and maybe that's the best I can do. I was hoping for something more ... elegant.

Comment: Yeah, if it's not that it could be a template column.